# Import error: No module named _mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to import MySQLdb using python 2.7, while I am getting the below error. I am new on Ubuntu, so unable to figure out where things are going wrong.

error message :

```
import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

Could you please help me out ?

i have used below commands to install python mysqldb

```
$ gunzip MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf MMySQL-python-1.2.4b4.tar
$ cd MySQL-python-1.2.4b4
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 9):

Install `python-mysqldb`:

You can intall this package in `Ubuntu` via this command:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: Might want to specify to python2-mysqldb.

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-mysqldb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-mysqldb

Answer (score 2):

### Python DB interface api "MySQLdb"installation @RHEL version 6.4

(Probably should work with other Unix Flv too).

I installed the MySQLdb Version 1.2.2 and faced the same problem
i.e ImportError: No module named _mysql

Note : Following explanation does tells anything about debugging the problem rather workaround by installing the "MySQLdb" version 1.2.5 which is working absolutely fine.

**steps followed :**

```
[user@hostname]$:wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mysql-python/MySQL-[user@hostname]$:python-1.2.2.tar.gz
[user@hostname]$:tar -xvf MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar
[user@hostname]$:cd MySQL-python-1.2.2
[user@hostname]$:python setup.py build
[user@hostname]$:python setup.py install
```

Note:user should have privilege to execute the command - sudo (advised) or else root user and installation was suceesful

**Later episode : ERROR** :-

```
[user@hostname]$: python 

Python 2.7.9 (default, May 23 2015, 09:01:18) 

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

**WORK AROUND :**
Renamed the Binary file "MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.6-linux-i686.egg" @location : /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages.
(Generally @location where the "MySQL....i686.egg" is created after executing the command "python setup.py install" or "sudo python setup.py install")

Better option is to uninstall MySQLdb version 1.2.2 or in other cases namely version 1.2.4 and check "MySQL....i686.egg" file does not exist.

```
[user@hostname site-packages]$ sudo mv MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.6-linux-i686.egg 123MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.6-linux-i686.123egg
```

**WHATS NEXT :**

1.go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

2.Download "MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip"
*i have downloaded "MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip" in the folder named "download"*

```
[user@hostname]$:cd download 
[user@hostname]$:unzip MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
[user@hostname]$:cd MySQL-python-1.2.5
[user@hostname]$:ls
doc      HISTORY  MANIFEST.in   _mysql.c  _mysql_exceptions.py   PKG-INFO       README.md  setup_common.py  setup.py          site.cfg
GPL-2.0  INSTALL  metadata.cfg  MySQLdb   MySQL_python.egg-info  pymemcompat.h  setup.cfg  setup_posix.py   setup_windows.py  tests
[user@hostnaem]$:sudo python setup.py install 
    running install
    ...............
.......................
    Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
    Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.5
    Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.5
[user@hostname]$:python  
    Python 2.7.9 (default, May 23 2015, 09:01:18) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import MySQLdb
    >>> import MySQLdb
    >>> dir(MySQLdb)
['BINARY', 'Binary', 'Connect', 'Connection', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DBAPISet', 'DataError', 'DatabaseError', 'Date', 'DateFromTicks', 'Error', 'FIELD_TYPE', 'IntegrityError', 'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'MySQLError', 'NULL', 'NUMBER', 'NotSupportedError', 'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'ROWID', 'STRING', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'Time', 'TimeFromTicks', 'Timestamp', 'TimestampFromTicks', 'Warning', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__revision__', '__version__', '_mysql', 'apilevel', 'connect', 'connection', 'constants', 'debug', 'escape', 'escape_dict', 'escape_sequence', 'escape_string', 'get_client_info', 'paramstyle', 'release', 'result', 'server_end', 'server_init', 'string_literal', 'test_DBAPISet_set_equality', 'test_DBAPISet_set_equality_membership', 'test_DBAPISet_set_inequality', 'test_DBAPISet_set_inequality_membership', 'thread_safe', 'threadsafety', 'times', 'version_info']
```

Import MySQLdb is working fine....FINALLY WORKING ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you will need to install  [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/).

The common way to install [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) is to use [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) as described here. But for Ubuntu,  the recommended way is what was mentioned in the previous answer:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

However, you will need first to install the necessary dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Now you should be able to import it: `>>> import MySQLdb`

Comment: I am getting the below error `>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
`

Comment: I have googled this, however, everywhere it is suggested to downgrade the MySQLdb version instead of upgrading the _mysql version. Do you have any solution for this ? @Bill

Comment: It means the MySQL Python interface is different from MySQL version you installed. You need to upgrade the later one (MySQL server) and it should work after that @Sourav

Comment: How does `ImportError: No module named _mysql` say that you need to install `MySQLdb` ?

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install python-mysql.connector